# Converting a text dataframe to a numeric data frame gives a list of NA

Tags: r

This is my code, I want to convert a dataframe of text to a numerical one :

```
library(reldist)

year_return[complete.cases(year_return), ]
year_returnGINI <- as.numeric(as.character(year_return[2:19]))
```

But, I get a list of NA instead of a numerical dataframe :

```
 [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
```

What should I do ?

Here is a sample of the dataset :

```
     Date         .SXQR       .SXTR    .SXNR      .SXMR      .SXAR       .SX3R       .SX6R    
[1,] "2000-01-03" " 364.9400" "223.93" "489.0400" "586.3800" " 306.5600" " 246.8100" "385.360"
[2,] "2000-01-04" " 345.0400" "218.90" "474.0500" "566.1500" " 301.1300" " 239.2400" "374.640"
[3,] "2000-01-05" " 338.2200" "215.88" "464.2000" "542.2900" " 298.2200" " 239.5500" "373.260"
```

Here is the link to [full dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1be3GMRNwwfGZm8gkJi-sWJMWnG6T4nYh)

<sub><s>**UPDATE** :</s></sub>

I want know to use the Gini Coefficient from the library [reldist](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/reldist/reldist.pdf).

My code is now :

```
library(reldist)

year_return <- read.csv("year_return.csv")
year_return[3:19] <- lapply(year_return[3:19], function(x) 
  as.numeric(as.character(x)))
year_return[[2]] <- as.Date(year_return[[2]])
str(year_return)

gini(year_return[3:19],w)
```

<sub>And I get this message error : **Error in `[.data.frame`(x, ox) : undefined columns selected.**</sub>

<sub>Note : 'w' is :</sub>

```
 [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]       [,7]       [,8]       [,9]
[1,] 0.04591712 0.04078667 0.04126135 0.05131896 0.04349168 0.04834431 0.04694083 0.03904389 0.04117694
          [,10]      [,11]      [,12]      [,13]      [,14]     [,15]      [,16]      [,17]     [,18]
[1,] 0.04537461 0.04692524 0.04045692 0.04696848 0.05087293 0.1713231 0.08499888 0.04396601 0.0708321
```

<sub>What should I do ?</sub>

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for at least one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very simple. Do not apply `as.numeric(as.character(.))` to a dataframe, apply it column vector by column vector.

```
year_return <- read.csv("year_return.csv")
year_return[3:19] <- lapply(year_return[3:19], function(x) 
  as.numeric(as.character(x)))
year_return[[2]] <- as.Date(year_return[[2]])
str(year_return)
```

Besides, the 2nd vector is a **date**.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help ! I do have an another issue as you can see in my UPDATE on my original post. Do you have any idea why ?

Comment: @Snooz3 The update is another question, related to the first but not at all the same. You should post it as a question on its own, since I believe it could be usefull to others (the main purpose of SO), with *a link to this question*. And please if you do, post the output of `dput(w)`, it becomes much easier for us to copy&paste into an R session.